# Dependency on x? Definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

Prove that the values of the $$\int_{-cos(x)}^{sin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt, x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$$

Do not depend on x.

---

I don't know what this means. I just found the derivative.

$$\leftrightarrow -\int_{0}^{-cos(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt + \int_{0}^{sin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$

$$= - (sin(x))\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-cos^2 (x)}} + cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-sin^2(x)}}$$

What now?

Comment: Hint: take the derivative with respect to $x$. Now think on what should happen to a function that does not depend on $x$ if you derive it with respect to $x$

Comment: Can you simplify $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$fx)=\int_{-cos(x)}^{sin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt, x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) 
\\\to \\
f'= - (sin(x))\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-cos^2 (x)}} + cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-sin^2(x)}}=\\
- (sin(x))\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin ^2 (x)}} + cos(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}}=\\\dfrac{-\sin x}{|\sin x|}+\dfrac{\cos x}{|\cos x|}$$
when $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \sin x>0 , \cos x >0$ so 
$$f'=\dfrac{-\sin x}{|\sin x|}+\dfrac{\cos x}{|\cos x|}=\\
\dfrac{-\sin x}{\sin x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x}=-1+1=0 $$
$f'=0 \to f(x)=const$ so f(x) does not depend on $x$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int_{-\cos(x)}^{\sin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$

$=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))-\sin^{-1}(-\cos(x))=$

$=\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))-\sin^{-1}(\sin\left(x-\frac{π}{2}\right)$

On this interval, this is equal to

$\displaystyle x-\left(x-\frac{π}{2}\right)=\boxed{\frac{π}{2}}$.